# Linux throttle disc writes

Tags: linux

I'm writing a shell script to copy gigabytes of data from directory A to directory B.

The script runs just fine, but it's absolutely eating the available resources - presumably disc read/writes?

Is there some way of throttling processes to limit their resource usage for disc / processor / ram etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux kernel has different scheduling classes for I/O. Use `ionice` command to benefit from them.

For example

```
ionice -c 3 your_copy_script.sh
```

would run your script in `idle` class, meaning script would only get I/O time whenever no other process needs it.

If you need to modify an already running process,

```
ionice -c 3 -p pid_of_your_program
```

would do it. See `man ionice` for more information.

Comment: Don't forget to ensure the CFQ scheduler is selected.  From the man page: *"Linux supports io scheduling priorities and classes since 2.6.13 with the CFQ io scheduler."*